pip does not recognize "install"
pip does not seem to recognize the command "install", when I run the command
python -m pip install -U requests,
I get the error as above.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for install

running pip alone and it gives the error 

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python311\python.exe"  "C:\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe" install requests': The system cannot find the file specified.

this happened after the reinstall, before it gave the same install error
I've uninstalled and installed Python about 3 times by now, running the command Python get-pip.py works but nothing changes.

python installation not setup correctly.
check python:
python --version

check pip:
python -m pip --version

verify where pip even is:
where pip

if pip is missing:
python -m ensurepip --upgrade

hope it helps

there seemed to be two python directories, one in c:\ which had pip but no python and the other one somewhere else, but running pip in commandline called the one in c: so i wiped that directory, issue is resolved thanks a lot
